# Running a 64-bit shell script on a 32-bit Linux architecture

Tags: linux, shell, x86, cpu-architecture

I have a 32-bit Linux OS on which I want to run a 64-bit Shell script. The source provider of the script cannot provide a 32-bit version and the file is pretty huge (900 MB).

Comment: A shell script is a text file.  There is thus no 32 or 64-bit version.  Or does the script contains an encoded binary file?

Comment: After a point, the script contains encoded characters only.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118343/run-64-bit-app-on-32-bit-ubuntu-system/362750#362750 - time to switch to 64bit already.

Comment: @Miracle. so why do you expect that the 32/64 bits difference is meaningful?

Comment: @Mat the system has been in production since many years and changing the architecture isn't possible.

Comment: @AProgrammer because the documentation for installing that script says that it is compatible with a x86_64 architecture.

Comment: If you insist on using an obsolete kernel that can't run 64-bit user-space processes (perhaps because your hardware is 32-bit-only Pentium 4?), the only thing you can do is run a 64-bit install in a VM (e.g. kvm), or *emulate* for just this process, e.g. with qemu-user.  That's not going to be at all fast; it's not executing the machine code natively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given little details about the script and system, the answer is also very general ...

Assuming the code is actually a shell script.

The top level script is probably an installer - "self-exploding" ZIP/tar, with the abinaries encoded as text. The script itself only validate the system configuration. From the comments look like software update.

One important question is about the binaries that will be created. If they are 64 bit, you will not be able to run them on a 32 bit environment. If your system is legacy, you might be behind on system libraries.

---

**If (unlikely)** the binaries are built to run as 32-bit, and only the installer itself required 64-bit, consider these options:

- Run the installer on 64 bit environment, directing the installation into new folder (/opt/mysoftware-1.2, or similar), then copy/tar all the created tree to the 32 bit system, including any environment/startup script. With luck, it might work.
- Alternatively, review the (installer) script, and try to see if possible to 'cheat'. May be the installer support environment variables that you can overwrite
- Consider upgrading the system to 64, and install legacy 32 libraries, while you can still find 32 bit libraries available. For work experience, we were able to run lot of 32 system libraries for 64 bit RedHat 6 (now obsolete).

  32-bit multiarch executables and libraries on a 64-bit system will be supported longer than fully 32-bit kernel + user-space by most distros.

Comment: 32-bit multiarch libraries will be around *much* longer than 32-bit versions of distros.  Running the odd 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system is still something most distros want to support, and probably will for a long time.  Especially libraries that WINE needs; people will have 32-bit Windows executables they want to run under WINE for the foreseeable future, and sometimes legacy 32-bit Linux binaries. You might have to build your own versions of some less-common 32-bit libraries, but it's different from distros like Arch already dropping support for 32-bit user-space.

Comment: Might worth separating commercial vendors (which tend to remove 32 bit support and libraries from their supported versions), vs. free distributions (which are less likely to remove support) as per comment from Peter. Not sure which setup the OP refers to.